# implementing google authentication in java with maven

Tags: java, maven, oauth-2.0

I'm getting a mysterious error when I try to execute Google's authentication example code which I got from here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate

I'm not even sure which information is relevant, so I'll start from the beginning. I copied and pasted the code directly. The only changes I made were:

1. I plugged my own authentication info in where it was required
2. I created a main method.
3. I imported some additional classes, including `com.google.api.client.http.UrlEncodedContent`

My modified version is here: https://gist.github.com/Glank/cac68a658a9b1aeb393c

I build and run the code using the following maven commands:

```
mvn clean install
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.mu.TestServlet"
```

My pom dependencies are here: https://gist.github.com/Glank/50fe98a9575e10df6a68

The code builds and executes with no issues other than a few encoding warnings.
It gives me a link.
I go, give myself permission to access the data and am redirected to a uri with a code parameter.
I copy and paste the parameter into standard input after the prompt, "What is the authorization code?"
Then suddenly, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.UrlEncodedContent: method <init>()V not found
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.executeUnparsed(AccessTokenRequest.java:444)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.execute(AccessTokenRequest.java:470)
    at org.mu.TestServlet.setUp(TestServlet.java:54)
    at org.mu.TestServlet.main(TestServlet.java:23)
```

I have looked at the source code for URLEncodeContent and AccessTokenRequest:

- AccessTokenRequest source code: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/draft10/AccessTokenRequest.java?r=8d2015927d8506e63e349129b093c033e074cbdd
- URLEncodedContent source code: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/http/UrlEncodedContent.java?r=8d2015927d8506e63e349129b093c033e074cbdd

No constructor is implemented for UrlEncodedContent. From what I've read this exception is thrown when the default constructor is being called but another constructor is implemented: [method init()v not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998202/method-initv-not-found)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The UrlEncodeWhatever class does not have a method with the right signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for sure what was causing the error, but I managed to get it working after starting from scratch and ignoring that particular code example. I assume the issue was with miss-matched versions of dependencies in my pom - now they are all version 1.15.1-rc. Anyways, here's my working code if anyone else has similar problems:

https://github.com/Glank/MinimalGoogleCalendarWebAccess